# Retrieve entry from table using foreign key (Hibernate)

Tags: java, database, hibernate, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I'm learning how to use Hibernate and I have a question relating to querying tables that have a one-to-one relationship.

There are two tables, `Employee` and `Account`, that have a one-to-one relationship. The primary key for an `Employee` is an employee id. I want to use this id for an `Account` and I understand that it can therefore be defined as a foreign key in the `Account` table.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee
{
    @Id
    private int employeeId;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Account
{
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employeeId", referencedColumnName = "employeeId", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="FK_Account_Employee"))
    private Employee employee;
}
```

Note that `Account` does not have an additional id field. The employee id foreign key is unique. Is this acceptable?

I have declared a repository interface for the `Account` as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer>
{
}
```

How do I retrieve an entry from this table using the employee id?

E.g. something like

```
accountRepository.getOne(employeeId)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to add the following method to your repository.

From the method naming of Spring Data JPA, this should retrieve your `Account` from the `id` field of its `Employee` object :

```
Account findByEmployee_Id(Integer employeeId)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be called `findByEmployeeId`?

Comment: No, this syntax would only work if `Account` had an `employeeId` integer field, instead of an `Employee` field. The underscore in the method name tells spring to look for the value of an attribute of a child object.